# The before superlative adverbs

Tags: adverbs

I have learnt that before "most" and "best" it's not wrong to omit the article. "Choose the dress you like (the) best/most." But before other adverbs do you always use it or it's not necessary? Would a native speaker omit them in my sentences?

1. "Ann finished the quickest."
2. "Sam talks the loudest of all the boys."

3."David's dog jumped the highest."

4."Barry slept the longest."

5."This computer model operates the  least efficiently."

6. "Tom and Lindsey arrived early but Luke arrived the earliest."
7. "She ran the furthest."
8. "He ate the least."
9. "She speaks English the worst."
10. "She ran the fastest."
11. "She understands grammar the hardest."

Comment: They are fine (other than 11.) The article "the" functions as a modifier of the adverb. 11. is not natural; consider instead "She finds grammar the hardest".

Comment: Do you mean they are fine with or without "the"?

Comment: Yes. The article used to be required as part of the construction, and it's still allowed in most circumstances, but it's optional. Leave it out if you wanna talk faster.

Comment: Thank you very much.   Would it be wrong to say that the article is always required before a superlative adjective and that's the only case when omitting it is wrong? For example, 1.  Josh is the fastest runner on the team." Omitting the article is wrong. 

2. "Caroline smiles the most sweetly." Without "the" "most sweetly" means very sweetly or Caroline is compared to other people and she smiles "the most sweetly" compared to others.

Comment: 3. "Our rotary telephone is the least frequently used device in our house." I don't know if it can be omitted or not. 

4. "Ben moved most quietly as the boys walked down the darkened ally." "The most quietly" would mean the same as in the second example. He is compared.

Comment: 5. "The last remark was the least clearly stated. I can't say if the article can be omitted. 

6. "Karen accepted the award most graciously." The same as #2 and #4. 

7. "The accident occurred most abruptly." I am not sure if the article can be used. 

8. "Lisa drives most carefully in heavy traffic." The same as #2 and #4. 

8. "I most anxiously await your arrival." I can't say if "the" can be added.

9. "Kerri most assuredly did not do what you accused her of." Not sure if "the" can be added.

Comment: @AntoniaA Yes, like all modifiers, "the" is optional here.

Comment: In sentences where it wasn't used it can be added. Right? In these ones #3, #5, #7, #8, #9.