# The least or least, the most or most?

Tags: superlatives

Can I omit "the" in #1 and #2 before "least" and add it before "most" in #3, #4, #5? Will the meaning change by adding and omitting it?

1. "Our rotary telephone is the least frequently used device in our house."
2. "The last remark was the least clearly stated."
3. "The accident occurred most abruptly."
4. "I most anxiously await your arrival."
5. "Kerri most assuredly did not do what you accused her of."

Comment: Antonia, we don't do this type of thing here (editing or proofreading). You put the burden on us and by adding those numbers, it makes us have to work even harder. Please put your remarks about your sample sentences **under or above them**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OMG, I legit wrote most of this answer before I realized who wrote the question. It totally fits with our earlier discussion.]

To be clear, there is nothing wrong with this question. OP is clearly not asking for editing or proofreading, but is rather asking for advice about categories of usage. Sentences 1 and 2 illustrate one category, 3-5 illustrate another.

The answer, quite simply, is that the sentences you have posted are 100% correct and should not be changed.

In #1, "**the** least frequently used device" is correct because you have used a superlative to identify a specific "device."

In #2, "the least clearly stated" is correct because the phrase is elliptical. It means "the least clearly stated **remark**." As in #1, you have used a superlative to identify a specific "remark."

The sentences are similar because the adverbs ("frequently" and "clearly") modify adjectives ("used" and "stated"), not verbs. Thus, the determiner "the" in each case attaches to a noun, ("device" and "remark," respectively).

In #3 - #5, the adverbs ("most abruptly," "most anxiously," and "most assuredly") modify **verbs** ("occurred," "await," and "did not do," **not** adjectives, and thus do not ultimately apply to nouns. Because there are no nouns, determiners such as "the" would not fit.

However, I would caution you that using "most" to modify an adverb sounds a bit old-fashioned (or stuffy) as does the word "assuredly"—at least in the USA.

Comment: Thank you, @Jeffrey Carney. I am not asking anyone to proofread my sentences. Thanks for understanding. This is probably one of hardest areas of grammar. If the article should not be omittedin these sentences why can it be omitted in sentences #5 and 8. 
 Is it because there is not a general rule and it depends on each sentence?https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/291401/the-before-superlative-adverbs?noredirect=1#comment543982_291401

Comment: 5. "This computer model operates the least efficiently."

8. "He ate the least." I have been told that "the" is optional in them. I am trying to understand when it's optional and when it's compulsory. And what's the difference between these sentences and the sentences in this thread

Comment: I most assuredly do not see anything old fashioned or stuffy about "most assuredly"

Comment: Antonia A, I would say "the" is compulsory when it introduces a real or implied noun phrase—i.e., when it modifies a noun phrase that follows. It is probably optional when "the" + *superlative* modify something that precedes them, such as the subject of the sentence or the verb of the same clause. In #8, you will have to decide if "the least" modifies an unstated noun phrase like "food" or if it modifies "he" in contrast to the other eaters. (It is a subtle distinction with no practical consequence. )

Comment: OK. But if in In #1, "the least frequently used device" is correct because you have used a superlative to identify a specific "device", isn't it the same with: "5. "This computer model operates the least efficiently."  I identify the model. However in #5 it's optional but in the computer example it's not. Why is it so?

Comment: In #1, the device is explicitly to the right of the adverbial phrase. In #2, it is implicitly to the right—there is what you might call a "slot" where "remark" could fit. There is no such slot to the right of the adverb in #5. Nevertheless, "the" is permissible in #5, and to my ears sounds the most natural.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: One more question, if you please. Regarding this sentence: 8. "He ate the least." You said  In #8, you will have to decide if "the least" modifies an unstated noun phrase like "food" or if it modifies "he" in contrast to the other eaters." If I know for sure that "the least" modifies "food" and/or "he" in contrast to other eaters, is  in this case  omitting "the" wrong?

Comment: Saying the words aloud today, I feel that using "the" sounds more natural in either case.

Comment: In either case as in with or without "the"? "He ate least" and "He ate the least" without adding more information about other eaters and the word "food". But if I added them (either the other eaters or food) would "the" be required? Sorry to bother you again, but it's not easy :(

Comment: I mean that I would personally use "the least" in *this* sentence regardless of what I wanted it to clarify. "He ate least" sounds incomplete somehow. I wish I could explain my intuition more thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you very much again.